NextJs 14 production pages resolve to 404
I'm trying to access the services page after a build and push. It builds fine, and pushes fine, but when I try to access dns/services it resolves to a 404. It works fine when I am running it on dev, I have no issues. It's not capitalizing I've no clue what I'm doing wrong. I thought maybe it was a reserved keyword so I tried changing services to train and I got the same problem.
I've added a photo below of the the results of building it, and the folder structure, client and admin are currently placeholders.



Question, what do you mean by dns/services? Where is your application deployed? Does this happen only for the /services page or does it happen with the rest?

so my domain name server/services so if it was google.com/services. I only have the one page. it's a REALLY small website. the other buttons/links are modals, /services is the only page. I just find it bizarre I have another nextjs site I made at the same time I have zero issues with.

Where is your application deployed then? Are you sure the deployment succeeded? Is the 404 page you're seeing the one that you have built or one from your deployment service? It doesn't look like your application is wrong, the problem could likely be at the server level.

I have it on firebase, this is the 2nd site I have on firebase. And I compared the configs and files to the site I have zero issues with and it all looks the "same". Maybe I should just start over and try again.
